# Laravel Datatable only searchs ID

Tags: laravel, datatables

I generated my Laravel CRUD views with [InfyOm](http://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/docs/5.5/introduction), which uses [Datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) to present it. It comes with a search field by default, but when I try to search it only searches by ID. I can't find how I can set to search in the other fields too. I can't find any documentation about how to implement this. It seems that it has something to do with [this](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/multi-filter-select), but I didn't get it. How can I make this?

Here is my Datatable class:

```
<?php

namespace App\DataTables;

use App\Models\SubscriptionStatus;
use Yajra\DataTables\Services\DataTable;
use Yajra\DataTables\EloquentDataTable;

class SubscriptionStatusDataTable extends DataTable
{
    /**
     * Build DataTable class.
     *
     * @param mixed $query Results from query() method.
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\DataTableAbstract
     */
    public function dataTable($query)
    {
        $dataTable = new EloquentDataTable($query);

        return $dataTable->addColumn('action', 'subscription_statuses.datatables_actions');
    }

    /**
     * Get query source of dataTable.
     *
     * @param \App\Models\Post $model
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function query(SubscriptionStatus $model)
    {
        return $model->newQuery();
    }

    /**
     * Optional method if you want to use html builder.
     *
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\Html\Builder
     */
    public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
            ->columns($this->getColumns())
            ->minifiedAjax()
            ->addAction(['width' => '80px', "title" => "Ações"])
            ->parameters([
                'dom'     => 'Bfrtip',
                'order'   => [[0, 'desc']],
                'buttons' => [
                    'export',
                    'print',
                    'reset',
                    'reload',
                ],
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get columns.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getColumns()
    {
        return [
            ['data' => 'name', 'title' => 'Nome'],
            ['data' => 'description', 'title' => 'Descrição'],
            ['data' => 'expire_days', 'title' => 'Tempo para Expirar'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get filename for export.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function filename()
    {
        return 'subscription_statusesdatatable_' . time();
    }
}
```